# Swift: swift access function in struct no init

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I'm trying to access to function in struct like this

```
struct DoSomething {
    var str: String

    func processNumber(number: Int) -> String {
        return "\(number)"
    }
}

let number = DoSomething().processNumber(number: 10)
print(number)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Missing argument for parameter 'str' in call
```

Any of you knows how can Access the function in the struct.

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe you want a `static func`?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a paramter like this be

```
let number = DoSomething(str:"someValue").processNumber(number: 10)
```

As there is no `()` init in that case , if you need it a separate logic do

```
class func processNumber(number: Int) -> String {
    return "\(number)"
}
```

and call like

```
let number = DoSomething.processNumber(number: 10)
```

> note if the var `var str: String`  has no usage you should not create it either

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize `str` when creating an instance of `DoSomething`.

Either assign a default value in the struct

```
struct DoSomething {

    var str: String = ""

    ....

}

let number = DoSomething().processNumber(number: 10)
```

Or in the initializer which has the signature `init(str : String)`

```
let number = DoSomething(str: "").processNumber(number: 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be resolved by declaring the `str` as an optional.

```
struct DoSomething {
    var str: String?

    func processNumber(number: Int) -> String {
        return "\(number)"
    }
}

let number = DoSomething().processNumber(number: 10)
print(number)
```